# Did loot from the 4th Crusade turn up in interesting places?

Tags: crusades, byzantine-empire, venice, loot

The [horses of St. Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horses_of_Saint_Mark) were taken to Venice. Are there any other objects that are known to have turned up elsewhere?

Comment: Note that St. Mark was/is the patron saint of Venice (some say he took over that position from an old pagan winged lion god), so items having to do with St. Mark have particular relevence there.

Answer (score 4):

The 'treasury' inside St. Mark's basilica in Venice has a *spectacular* collection of byzantine artifacts.

Comment: Interesting! But what about other, more unexpected, places?